# Estilizar input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Existe algum jeito de estilizar um input type file e deixa-lo assim?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tentei estilizar via css mas não tive sucesso. Não consigo pensar em algum jeito de fazer isso.

Comment: por favor cole seu código para que possamos auxiliar/ajudar melhor, assim saberemos o que você já conseguiu

Comment: Não sei se isso não envolve algo em html também, então não vou colar o código e deixar livre

Comment: provavelmente da para fazer s'o com html e css, sem usar alguma framework ou bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O truque é fazer o `input file` invisível, com `opacity: 0 !important;` e por detrás dele criar um botão ou seja uma `div` personalizada/estilizada da maneira que nós queremos que o botão fique (que neste caso iremos tentar criar algo como no exemplo da tua imagem) que irá dar o visual a esta caixa de seleção de ficheiros.

Como o `input file` oculto, apenas a `div` personalizada que ficará por detrás do  `input file` com uma `position:absolute;` ficará visível, resultando em algo como no exemplo que criei abaixo e deixando o `input file` clicável pois se encontra na frente do botão personalizado.

Aqui tens também um [exemplo no jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/wkgavgaL/) se preferires.

```css
.formWrapper {
    border: 3px solid #C2B2B3;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.upload {
    width: 200px;
    height: 57px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F3F1E9;
    float: left;
}

div.upload input {
    display: block !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 57px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    cursor: text;
}
.upload user agent stylesheetdiv input[type="button"], .upload input[type="submit"], .upload input[type="reset"], .upload input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button, .upload button {
    cursor: text !important;
    /* Correção para Botáo Fantasma - forçar cursor:text */
}

.inputFileOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #7B5368;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 57px;
    text-align: center;
}

.formWrapper input.enviar {
    float: left;
    height: 57px;
    background-color: #7B5368;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="formWrapper">
        <div class="upload">
            <div class="inputFileOverlay">Selecione o arquivo</div>
            <input type="file" name="upload"/>
        </div>
        <input class="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar →">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado!!! +111111